# Can I use my normal (html) form in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Can I use my normal (html) form in Zend Framework ? How can I do that & How can I call action in IndexController file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course you can ... just use

```
<form action="/index/action" methode="POST">
```

to access post arguments use

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('argument')
```

Answer (score 1):

thats no problem, put your form code inside the view script for the associated action. Maybe:

```
formAction() 
{
   // check if post request
   if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {       
       // read global $_POST array
       $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   }
}
```

the associated view ist than form.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely.. You just have to remove the isValid call in your controller since it won't be performing any validation and also remove the post request check if it will not contain any form. It's like creating a common view with simple links in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have a module called 'contact', and an action `addcontactAction()` in the ContactController.php.

So I can use :
/view/scripts/contacts/addcontact.phtml

```
<form  action="" method="post" name="frm_addcontact" />
<input name="cn_fname" type="text" class="textbox" id="cn_fname"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" id="save" value="Save" />
</form>
```

when this form is submitted, it calls `addcontactAction()` in the controller.

```
$cn_fname       = $_REQUEST['cn_fname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to know this is not a good practice to implement, but to solve such problem do the following: 
in the view file when you define the form

```
    <form action = "<?php echo $this->url(array('action'=>'ACTIONAME')); ?>" ...>
................
</form>
```

in the corresponding action name

```
 if($this->_request->isPost()){
        foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) { 
        echo "$var = $value<br>"; 
        }
```